# how to find diffrence between two dates in secods stored as varchar2 in PLSQL/SQL

Tags: java, sql, datetime, select, plsql

I have the below java method which will find the difference of two dates in seconds, it is working fine.

```
public class dateconvetr {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        long differenceInMillis = 0;
        long diffInSecs =0;
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS");
        SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS");
        Date date1 = sdf.parse("09122014165749983");
        Date date2 = sdf2.parse("09122014175749983");
        System.out.println("get time2 is:" + date2.getTime() );
        System.out.println("get time 1:" + date1.getTime() );

        differenceInMillis = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        System.out.println("differenceInMillis:"+differenceInMillis);
        diffInSecs = differenceInMillis/1000;
        System.out.println("diffInSecs"+diffInSecs);
    }

}
```

now I want to do the same operation from PL/SQL, where I need to get the difference of two dates (stored as `varchar2` in table in `MMddyyyyHHmmssSSS` format ) in seconds.
I tried but I am getting some wrong values:

```
select round(param_x-param_y )*86400 FROM table_x;
```

Comment: You should **not** store timestamps as `varchar`. Never

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this as follows, it may not be a good logic, but my problem solved. First took out the Milliseconds part from the date and calculated the duration separately.

```
        strTime1 varchar2(50);
        strTime2 varchar2(50);
        v_date1 date ;
        v_date2 date;
        actualStartDate varchar2(50);
        actualEndDate varchar2(50);
        startmillisec varchar2(50);
        endmillisec varchar2(50);
        difrence_In_Hours number;
        difrence_In_minutes number;
        difrence_In_seconds number := 0;
        difrence_In_milliseconds number := 0;

        SELECT val_x INTO V_F_LEG FROM table_x WHERE PARAM_ss=i.PARAM_ss AND PARAM_ff= '1';

       SELECT PARAM_rr INTO V_L_LEG FROM table_x WHERE PARAM_ss=i.PARAM_ss AND PARAM_ff= '2' AND PARAM_gg IS NOT NULL;

            actualStartDate := substr(V_F_LEG,1,14);
            actualEndDate :=  substr(V_L_LEG,1,14);
            -- handling milliseconds seperately

            startmillisec := substr(V_F_LEG,15,3);
            endmillisec := substr(V_L_LEG,15,3);

            v_date1  := to_date(actualStartDate,'YYYYMMDDHHmiSS');
            v_date2 := to_date(actualEndDate,'YYYYMMDDHHmiSS');
               difrence_In_milliseconds := endmillisec - startmillisec;
               difrence_In_Hours   := (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24;
               difrence_In_minutes := difrence_In_Hours * 60;
               if abs(difrence_In_milliseconds) > 500 then
               difrence_In_seconds := round((difrence_In_minutes * 60)+1);
              else
              difrence_In_seconds := round(difrence_In_minutes * 60);
              end if;

            V_DURATION := difrence_In_seconds;
```

Answer (score 1):

The concept is right, but you're missing a conversion of these varchar values to timestamps, like you did in Java. Additionally, to improve the precision, it would be better to round after the multiplication instead of before:

```
SELECT ROUND((TO_TIMESTAMP(param_x, 'mmddyyyyhh24missFF3') -  
              TO_TIMESTAMP(param_y, 'mmddyyyyhh24missFF3')) * 86400) 
FROM   table_x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am getting error as "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP". could you please help ?

Comment: @Msn I messed up the brackets, apologies. The subtraction should happen first (hence should be surrounded by brackets), then the multiplication, and then the rounding. See my edited answer.

Comment: could you please recheck the answer, still am getting "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND" error